# How to put unicode in Cmd/Batch?

Tags: batch, unicode

So, i'm trying to make a nice batch menu but everytime i try to use unicode's fancy lines i just get random characters.
Is there any way to put unicode in cmd and or a batch file?

Comment: Put this in your batch `chcp 65001` This will change it to utf-8

Comment: This worked, but how do i set it as default?

Comment: Explained below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use unicode, add the code `chcp 65001`

This will change the code page. It stays that way until you close the window.

If you want to have this always run, (not necessarily recommended, because unicode can sometimes break batches), you can add a reg key string **(reg_sz)** to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor** and name it **AutoRun**. Change the value of it to `chcp 65001`. If you don't want to see the output message from the command, use `@chcp 65001>nul` instead.

Comment: Thx m8, put this as the answer. When i was searching around this is the best answer ever posted :)