# Change permanently terminal encoding in windows 10

Tags: windows-7, terminal, encoding, utf-8

When I type in the cmd `chcp 65001`" and then close it, when reopening it resets to the default "850".

I need to be able to run my C++ program with utf8 but I can't if it keeps reseting itself...

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

To use unicode, add the code `chcp 65001`

This will change the code page. It stays that way until you close the window.

If you want to have this always run, (not necessarily recommended, because unicode can sometimes break batches), you can add a reg key string **(reg_sz)** to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor** and name it **AutoRun**. Change the value of it to chcp 65001. If you don't want to see the output message from the command, use @chcp 65001>nul instead.

Reference from my own post: [How to put unicode in Cmd/Batch?](https://superuser.com/questions/1075297/how-to-put-unicode-in-cmd-batch/1075619#1075619)